# Filter rows from joined table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I´m struggling with an issue that seems simple but I cannot find the solution:

I have a simple model to upload multiple photos to an item.

```
Class Item:
name: string

Class Photo:
item = ForeignKey(Item)
image: ImageFile
default: Boolean
```

I want to get all the Items from the REST API but only with the default photo.

Righ now I have:

```
Class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset=Item,objects.all()
   serializer_class=ItemSerializer

Class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Photo
      fields = ['image',
                'default']

Class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   photos=PhotoSerializer(source='photo_set', many=True)
   class Meta:
      model = Item
      fields = ['id',
                'name',
                'photos']
```

The problem is that I get all the photos of the Item. I don't know how to filter the Photos table to retrieve only the photos with default=True.

It cannot be so difficult. Any help??

Appreciate it very much.

Dalton

Comment: `photos=Photo.objects.filter(default=True)`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your tip, Daniel. I wish it was so simple. Notice the queryset is run on the table Item, not on the table Photo. I need to apply the filter on the subordinate table, which is called in the serializer. I tried to apply this filter in the serialier, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this problem, and I just want to share in case someone else is in similar situation:

Steps:

1. Add a related_name property to the ForeignKey:

```
Class Photo:
item = ForeignKey(Item, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image: ImageFile
default: Boolean
```

2. Add a method in the serializer with the queryset and the filter you want

```
Class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Photo
      fields = ['image',
                'default']

Class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   photos=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   class Meta:
      model = Item
      fields = ['id',
                'name',
                'photos']

   def get_photos(self, obj):
      queryset = obj.photos.filter(default=True)
      return PhotoSerializer(queryset, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

And voila, it works!!!.

Dalton